# Linux - Bash & Expect

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I use expect to copy my key to remote linux boxes.

**copy_key**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

stty echo 
set REMOTEhost [lindex $argv 0]
set REMOTEpass [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/myuser/mykey.pub root@$REMOTEhost

expect "password: "

send "$REMOTEpass\n"

sleep 2
```

This is called via `./copy_key 1.1.1.1 GENERATED_PASSWORD`

I'd like to migrate all of this to a bash script.

Something like the following, which of course is something different but just to help with an idea:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" { eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no usr@$myhost.example.com; interact }'
```

This doesnt work

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-copy-id -i /home/myuser/mykey.pub root@$REMOTEhost
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to get rid of expect or you want to wrap this in a shell script for some reason? Why?

Comment: I tried getting rid of it but it doesn't work. It needs to be adapted. This is a requirement so all must be on the same bash script.

Comment: At the moment you have a single expect script. You want to replace it with a bash script *without* expect? Or a bash script that uses expect? What's the requirement exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the 1:1 bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
stty echo && expect -c "spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/myuser/mykey.pub root@$1; expect \"password: \"; send \"$2\r\"; sleep 2;"
```

Comment: $1 and $2 being paramenters, so it would be like the following?
stty echo && expect -c "spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/myuser/mykey.pub root@$REMOTEhost; expect \"password: \"; send \"$REMOTEpass\r\"; sleep 2;" ?

Comment: If the expect example worked for you, this one should work too.

Comment: Do i need "/usr/bin/expect" in front?
/usr/bin/expect stty echo && expect -c "spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/myuser/mykey.pub root@$REMOTEhost; expect \"password: \"; send \"$REMOTEpass\r\"; sleep 2;"

Comment: If you are creating a bash script, then put the output of the `which bash` in its header. If `which expect` or `type expect` return the expect path in your root file-system, then you don't need to replace expect with /path/to/expect in the example provided. Nothing expect-related should stay in front of the one-liner.