# Avoid bash script waiting for user enter the Enter key

Tags: linux, bash, unix, mailx

i got following entry in a bash script.

```
 echo "Please see attached file" | mailx -S smtp=$smtpServer -s "Subject of the mail" -a $logfile -r "sender@domain.com" receiver1@domain.com receiver2@domain.com
```

Its working fine if there is no error in sending mail. but sometimes if there is an error ,mailx will show the error message and wait for user to enter the enter key(carriage return).I want to avoid this.it should not wait for user to enter the enter key . how to do it in bash script ?

Comment: Configure a local mail server as relay to $smtpServer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect command to look for matching text and set the value to be key-in. This will automatically keyin the value when it sees the text.

Solution to the below question might be useful.
[Linux - Bash & Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673596/linux-bash-expect)

Also please refer.
http://sharadchhetri.com/2010/12/07/how-to-use-expect-in-bash-script/